# What would be the output distribution of ReLu(X) activation (In case that the distribution of X is unknown)?

Tags: distributions, expected-value, symmetry

Suppose E[X]=0, var(X)=1 and we know X has a symmetric distribution, What would be the distribution of =ReLU()=max{0,}?

I have seen this question [What would be the output distribution of ReLu activation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392226/what-would-be-the-output-distribution-of-relu-activation?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but in that question, they have assumed ∼(,2).

Comment: @Artem Mavrin, Thank for your answer, do you have any idea for this question?

Answer (score 3):

As derived in [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392230/97872) to the [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/392226/97872), if $X$ is *any* random variable with some cumulative distribution function $F_X$ (i.e.,
$$
F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$), then $Y = \operatorname{ReLU}(X) = \max\{X, 0\}$ will be a random variable whose cumulative distribution function $F_Y$ is given by
$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y)
= \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $y < 0$} \\
F_X(x) &\text{if $y \geq 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.
This is the most that can be said at this level of generality (i.e., without assuming *anything* about the distribution of $X$), but if the distribution of $X$ were known, then this formula for the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ would completely characterize the distribution of $Y$.

Some remarks that follow:

1. If $X$ is absolutely continuous (i.e., has a probability density function), then $Y = \operatorname{ReLU}(X)$ is absolutely continuous *if and only if* $X$ takes only non-negative values almost surely (i.e., $P(X \geq 0) = 1$).
   This is because the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ has a jump discontinuity at $0$ if and only if $F_X(0) = P(X \leq 0) > 0$.
   But if $X$ takes only non-negative values, then $X = Y$, so this case is uninteresting.
   Thus, if $X$ can take negative values with positive probability, then $Y$ has no chance of having a density.
2. If $X$ is discrete (i.e., almost surely takes only countably many values), then $Y$ is also discrete, as its cumulative distribution function will be piecewise constant.

## Edit

I wasn't reading the question carefully: I missed the assumption about $X$ having a symmetric distribution with mean zero and unit variance.
The distribution of $Y$ in this case will clearly not have a symmetric distribution anymore, and its mean will be given by
$$
E[Y] = \int_0^\infty (1 - F_X(x)) \, dx.
$$
This follows from the general fact that if $Z$ is a non-negative random variable, then
$$
E[Z] = \int_0^\infty P(Z > z) \, dz.
$$

Comment: Thanks, X is discrete. If x_i be uncorrelated could we estimate the mean and variance of Y?

Comment: @MohammadJavad I think it would it be best if you ask that as a new question