# Output Distribution of ReLU given a Laplace Distribution as its Input

Tags: laplace-distribution, truncated-distributions

If input to a ReLU function (Max(X, 0)) is a Laplace Distribution, what would be the output distribution? will it have a density function? how would it look like? assuming that mean of the Laplace is 0, is it correct that ReLU cause the output be a cumulative Laplace truncated from below at x=0? I have read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392226/what-would-be-the-output-distribution-of-relu-activation) that displays the output of ReLU when input is a Gaussian but I have difficulty understanding it (mostly the notation). I would appreciate it if you could explain the steps to me (when input is a Laplace).